# WCF Service with Basic Auth over HTTP

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I'm developing a WCF Service Application with

- Server hosting the app is in domain
- Authorize client using basic authentication
- mapping username and password to AD user
- **HTTP**
- IIS only allow Basic Auth

I have found [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733775.aspx), but this is a sample for **HTTPS**.

Huge mount tries on web.config has been made, but I cannot figure out how to config.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: the tutorial is HTTPS related because you should not be passing credentials through HTTP

Comment: In general, yes. But in the internal and protected network, HTTP will be a option.

Answer (score 1):

you can change the binding to be basic binding instead of wsBining

```
<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicBinding" receiveTimeout="00:01:00"
          sendTimeout="00:01:00">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
```

an other option you can add a custom user validation method (Class) to your application and create your authentication inside of it

```
<serviceBehaviors>
<behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
<useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress />
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
<serviceCredentials>
<clientCertificate>
<authentication customCertificateValidatorType="WCFServices.clsCertificateValidator, App_Code/WCFServices" certificateValidationMode="Custom" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
</clientCertificate>
<userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"              customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WCFServices.clsUserValidator, App_Code/WCFServices" />
<peer>
<peerAuthentication customCertificateValidatorType="WCFServices.clsCertificateValidator, App_Code/WCFServices" certificateValidationMode="Custom" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
<messageSenderAuthentication customCertificateValidatorType="WCFServices.clsCertificateValidator, App_Code/WCFServices" certificateValidationMode="Custom" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
</peer>
<issuedTokenAuthentication audienceUriMode="Never" customCertificateValidatorType="WCFServices.clsCertificateValidator, App_Code/WCFServices" certificateValidationMode="Custom" revocationMode="NoCheck" allowUntrustedRsaIssuers="true" />
</serviceCredentials>
</behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

And in this class if you need to stop the user throw exception.